# On the set $U_p=\{x\in X: p(x)\le 1\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff locally convex topological vector space whose topology is generated by a family of continuous seminorms on $X$. For each continuous seminorm $p$ on $X$, let 
$$U_p=\{x\in X: p(x)\le 1\}.$$
Well, I know that $U_p$ is convex, absorbing and balanced.

**Question.** Is $U_p$ closed? If yes, can you please explain. I need some help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been making silly mistakes today, so correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't the complement of $U_p$ the set $\{ x \in X : p(x) > 1 \} = p^{-1}(1, + \infty)$, which is open by the continuity of $p$?

Comment: Yeah, but actually I noticed (after I posted my question) that$U_p=p^{-1}([0,1])$ and hence a closed set beccause $p$ is continuous.:)